# NTLM Authentication works on eclipse but tomcat gives 401 unauthorized

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, authentication, ntlm, jcifs

I used JCIFS to make NTLM authentication, it works fine as a stand alone application but when I deploy this module to tomcat server 5.5 I get 401 unauthorized, however I am able to run it on the same machine using same credentials but on eclipse as java stand alone application. Anyone helps?

Comment: "Run as standalone" means running from Eclipse in Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was in jars loading, I had to add the jars in JRE not in tomcat lib